# How can i Convert the DatePicker Input to string

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following Codes to get the date from the date picker

```
objDD_ml.EffDate=(DirectCast(drv.Cells(3).FindControl("rdpEffDate"), RadDatePicker).DateInput).ToString
```

But it does not return the date... It returns like 'DateInput'

How can i use the code to get the value for Effdate as a correct format of date

Anyone please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want date into string and in specific format you can always apply following :

```
objDD_ml.EffDate = (
    DirectCast(drv.Cells(3).FindControl("rdpEffDate"), RadDatePicker).DateInput
).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the `FindControl` object into the corresponding ASP control externally. Then access the value of that control and convert it to `.ToString`

I don't know what control you are using, but it should be something like below -

```
objDD_ml.EffDate = ((RadDatePicker)(drv.Cells[i].FindControl("rdpEffDate")).SelectedDate.Tostring;
```